# Is there an alternative to jest-environment-jsdom for jest tests using the window object

Tags: jestjs

I'm writing jest unit tests of some angularjs code that expects the windows object. The unit tests are failing because of this error:

> Reference Error: window is not defined

The default mode for jest is "node". If I want to use "jsdom" (which would add a window object), then I need to install jest-environment-jsdom. However, when trying to install jest-environment-jsdom, I encounter node-gyp errors. I looked up node-gyp installation help and found:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Which tells me that I need to install VS Build tools. This is a huge installation. I'm looking for an alternative solution that won't require other dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still a topic, but you can use

```
{
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "window": {
        "baseUri": "testUri"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in your package.json